# Nested group iterations with regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have a string like like:

```
Hello +++this--- is a funny +++string--- with words inside
```

I need to look for words surrounded by `+++` and `---` and replace the `+++` and `---` signs with `html` tags like `<a>word</a>`.

So that the text above becomes:

```
Hello <a>this</a> is a funny <a>string</a> with words inside
```

I'm currently using the following regex with a `sub` instruction:

```
rgx = re.compile(r'(?:\+\+\+)(?P<word>.+)(?:\-\-\-)')
output = rgx.sub('<a>\\g<word></a>')
```

And the output I get is:

```
Hello <a>this--- is a funny +++string</a> with words inside
```

As you can see, only the first and last `+++`/`---` are taken into account. The ones in the middle seems to be ignored. Obviously the big string between first and last `+++`/`---` match my regex.

How can I get `re` to match all groups one by one, and not consider the big overlapping match?

*Note: I've tried with `^\+` and `^\-` in the capturing group, but it doesn't work because a `+` or `-` could be in any word and should be kept as is, as long as it's not `+++` or `---`.*

Comment: You can use [`\+\+\+(?P<word>.+?)---`](https://regex101.com/r/lF2bR4/1) or even [`\+{3}(\w+)-{3}`](https://regex101.com/r/rF0dR9/1)

Comment: You can also use `string.replace('+++', '<a>')` and `string.replace('---', '</a')`. implementation could be taken further `string.replace('+++', '<%s>'%tag_name)`